# What percentage of internet users reject cookies?

Tags: statistics

What percentage of internet users don't accept cookies by default? (persistent and session cookies).

Couldn't find *any* current data, only estimates.

Comment: There can only be estimates as there is no way to know this information definitively. The same thing applies to javascript.

Comment: @JohnConde that's not really true, users without cookies are still logged (server log file).

Comment: But that information varies from site to site just like browsers usage. A b2b site will get more IE users and a tech site will get more Firefox and Chrome users. Even all of the companies that publicly disclose browser statistics offer big differences in browser marketshare. There just is no way to get solid numbers on these kind of things. Your only true recourse is to check your own log files.

Comment: @JohnConde Yes true - but I'd be happy to have ANY real numbers for a average audience (we're operating some big classified platforms and the audience isn't far of from my countries average).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to collect this info for your site for it to be any more than a general estimate. For example, the number of users who have things like Javascript, cookies and ads blocked is about 25% for my programming blog but it's less than 1% for a women's products review blog my wife writes.

You can find general estimates, like those from StatCounter, to be helpful when you're starting a new site but eventually you'll want to cater what you're doing in terms of cookies and scripts to your specific audience.